# Kotlin: RecycleView with firebase "must not be null" error

Tags: android, kotlin, device

I have a lot of difficulty with an android store app I'm creating.

I'm getting an error message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: products_list must not be null
```

My recycle view is connected to my firestore, the app runs but then I get that Logcat error message.
I'm using a Nav drawer home fragment to display my RecycleView.

I hope someone can assist me

HomeActivity.kt

```
const val TAG: String = "HOMEPAGE_LOG"
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val firebaseRepo: FirebaseRepo =
    FirebaseRepo()

private var productList: List<ProductModel> = ArrayList()
private val productListAdapter: ProductListAdapter = ProductListAdapter(productList)

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    products_list.layoutManager  = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    products_list.adapter = productListAdapter
    if(firebaseRepo.getUser() == null){
        // create new user
        firebaseRepo.createUser().addOnCompleteListener{
            if (it.isSuccessful){
                loadProductData()
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "Error:${it.exception!!.message}")
            }
        }
    } else {
        //user logged in
        loadProductData()
    }

    products_list.layoutManager  = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    products_list.adapter = productListAdapter

    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

private fun loadProductData() {
firebaseRepo.getProductList().addOnCompleteListener{
    if(it.isSuccessful){
        productList = it.result!!.toObjects(ProductModel::class.java)
        productListAdapter.productListItems = productList
        productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: ${it.exception!!.message}")
    }
}
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `products_list` with the id of your recycler view is. Something like:
`val products_list = findViewById(R.id.product_list)`

Comment: Where would I implement this? - Thanks!

Comment: Anywhere above where you're trying to reference it. So above the line:     `products_list.layoutManager  = LinearLayoutManager(this)`

Comment: Gives me an error for the "findViewById" part :( Do I remove the layout manager section?